# Multiple sliders with JQuery with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, slider

I am trying to build a slider that changes images depending on the region one clicks on a map. I want to use arrays to store images in the js file, not to list them in the HTML.
However, the console reports "imageArray[imageIndex]:1  GET http://localhost:8000/imageArray[imageIndex] 404 (File not found)"

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<img id="mainImage" src="Photos/OG/P1000609.JPG" style="width:100%">
<button onClick="changeImage()">next</button>
```

JQuery

```
var imageArray = ["Photos/OG/P1000389.jpg", "Photos/OG/P1000409.jpg","Photos/OG/P1000589.jpg"];
var imageIndex =0;

function changeImage(){
$("#mainImage").attr("src", "imageArray[imageIndex]");
imageIndex ++;
sliderLenght = imageArray.lenght;
if (imageIndex> sliderLenght) {imageIndex = 0}
};


function changeArray(e){
    imageArray = e
}

var region1Array= ["Photos/OG/P1000412.jpg", "Photos/OG/P1000414.jpg"];

$("#region1").click(changeArray(region1Array));
```

I tried substituting the images, and the folders but it does not work. Is there a way to make it work using arrays, or even just to find this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the paths of your images are stored in the array `imageArray`, you should just assign it directly to the `attr()`. Don't enclose it with quote or doublequotes.

Besides that, JavaScript array length should be `array.length`, but it was typo in your code that you wrote it as `lenght`.

In the snippet below, I change the mechanism to change the index first responding to the click then assign the element at the current index (after updated) of the `imageArray` to the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

```js
var imageArray = ["https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000708374642-k6d7gm-t500x500.jpg", "https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/so-logo-s.jpg"];
var imageIndex =0;

function changeImage(){
  var sliderLenght = imageArray.length;
  if (imageIndex < sliderLenght - 1) {
    imageIndex++;
  } else imageIndex = 0;
  
  $("#mainImage").attr("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img id="mainImage" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000708374642-k6d7gm-t500x500.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button onClick="changeImage()">next</button>
</div>
```

---

Besides that, you can improve the code by removing the `onClick` attribute on `button` and add the click event listener on the Javascript

```js
var imageArray = ["https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000708374642-k6d7gm-t500x500.jpg", "https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/so-logo-s.jpg"];
var imageIndex =0;

$('#button').click(() => {
  var sliderLenght = imageArray.length;
  if (imageIndex < sliderLenght - 1) {
    imageIndex++;
  } else imageIndex = 0;
  
  $("#mainImage").attr("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img id="mainImage" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000708374642-k6d7gm-t500x500.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button id="button">next</button>
</div>
```